# I cannot initialize Flask SocketIO with app.from_object parameter

Tags: flask-socketio

I have an app.py file where I initialize my app. I have another file (run.py) where I run Flask server from. Everything works with a standard flask app. However I am trying to integrate flask-socketio and it keeps failing with different errors depending on how I try to initialize the app.

I have tried the following ways to initialize flask-socketio:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app.config.from_object(app_config[env_name]))
socketio = SocketIO(app, **app.config[env_name])
socketio = SocketIO(**app.config[env_name])
```

Here is the relevant code from my app.py file.

```
def create_app(env_name):
  """
  Create app
  """

  # app initiliazation
  app = Flask(__name__)

  app.config.from_object(app_config[env_name])
  async_mode = None

  # initializing bcrypt and db
  bcrypt.init_app(app)
  db.init_app(app)
  socketio = SocketIO(app.config.from_object(app_config[env_name]))
  return socketio
```

My run.py file looks like this:

```
rom src.app import create_app

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

env_name = os.getenv('FLASK_ENV')
app = create_app(env_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  port = os.getenv('PORT')
  # run app
  app.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

You will notice I am importing from a config.py file. That is where my environment variables are being for (dev, test, prod). Each environment is it's own class. For example:

```
class Development(object):
    """
    Development environment configuration
    """
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = False
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False
    JWT_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('JWT_SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')
    ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])
    UPLOADED_FILES_DEST = os.getenv('UPLOADED_FILES_DEST')
```

As you can see, most of those values are set in an environment variable since it is bad practice to put such sensitive information into a repo.

I would like to be able to initialize flask-socketio so I can setup rooms where users can share location based information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I cannot instantiate SocketIO in my app.py file. I have to export app from my app.py file and instantiate SocketIO in my run.py file. My final code looks like this:

app.py

```
def create_app(env_name):
  """
  Create app
  """

  # app initiliazation
  app = Flask(__name__)

  app.config.from_object(app_config[env_name])

  # initializing bcrypt and db
  bcrypt.init_app(app)
  db.init_app(app)

  return app
```

Finally, my run.py file looks like this.

```
import os
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room, emit
from src.app import create_app

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

env_name = os.getenv('FLASK_ENV')
app = create_app(env_name)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  port = os.getenv('PORT')
  # run app
  socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Flask-SocketIO extensions takes the application instance as an argument. You should configure the application and then initialize it. For example:

```py
app.config.from_object(app_config[env_name])
socketio = SocketIO(app)
```

Comment: Sorry, that did not work. gives a similar error as above.